# HTML output from a js file

Tags: javascript, html

At this moment, I am trying to learn javascript, but it is giving me a hard time.

I have written a small rock paper scissors script, which should give some output to the user, but I seem unable to actually get that output.

The js script is like this:

```
var computerChoiceLine = 0
var tieResult = "The result is a tie!";
var winResult = "You won!";
var lossResult = "You lost..."
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose rock, paper or scissors?");
var computerChoice = Math.random();
// convert computerChoice into text
if (computerChoice <= 0.34) {
    computerChoiceLine = "rock";
} else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
    computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
    computerChoice = "scissors";
}
// convert userChoice into number
if (userChoice == "rock") {
    userChoiceNumber = 0;
} else if(userChoice == "paper") {
    userChoiceNumber = 0.50;
} else if(userChoice == "scissors"){
    userChoiceNumber = 1;
} else {
    userChoiceNumber = 100;
}

var output = function(choice1, choice2){
document.write("You chose " + choice1)
document.write("\n The computer chose " + choice2)
compare(userChoiceNumber , computerChoice)

var compare = function(choice1 , choice2){
    if(choice1 == choice2){
        document.write(tieResult);
    }
    if(choice1 < choice2){
        document.write(lossResult);
    }
    if(choice1 > choice2){
        document.write(winResult);
    }
};

if(userChoice == 100){
document.write("Please type rock, paper or scissors")
} else {
output(userChoice , computerChoiceLine);
};
}
```

And I call for it in HTML like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="RockPaperScissors.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can anyone please explain what I am doing wrong, and how I should change it?

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: You call `compare` before actually defining it. Do you miss the output of `tieResult`?

Comment: As I see, I have defined compare, before calling it.
And I don't get any errors, I just get a blank web page, and it does doe the prompt, but the page remains blank

Comment: never mind, with the answer of @skishore this issue is resolved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a missing close brace at the end of your definition of `output` and an extra close brace at the end of your js. After I made those changes the script worked.

Comment: Thanks a ton, that made it work! And testing it, made me realise that my compare function makes no sense XD